# Small Sample Size and NOT normally distributed

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, normalization, standardization, small-sample

Say $n_1=4$ and $n_2 = 5$. If I want to compare the mean, should I:

1. Standardize the data (i.e., using the scale() function in R), then perform t-test. This is because t-test required the data to be normally distributed.
2. Use non-parametric test such as Mann-Whitney U test.

Which one should I choose to do and why?
*I understand it is hard to compare data with only 9 observations, but the samples are very hard to obtain.

Side question: I know normalization means making the data into a specific range (i.e., usually range(0,1)) and we usually use it to make data into the same unit scale. But why? isn't standardization a better choice?

Comment: 1. normalize how exactly, standardize how exactly? 2. Why would you do either? 3. What do you know about the distribution? Presumably you're not judging it from 4 observations.

Comment: because t-test required normal distribution, so I think I will need to normalize the data.

Comment: Again, *how*? Please explain - in your question - precisely what you mean by "normalize" and by "standardize" and how you expect that these would be achieved with 4 and 5 observations. Please note in particular that the `normalization` tag does not mean "to transform to be normally distributed". It more usually means "to scale to be between 0 and 1".

Comment: You will need to edit your question to clarify your intent under options 1 and 2. It would be good if you could address the other issues I raised as well

Comment: The $\frac{x-\bar{x}}{s}$ transform is called normalization, yes, but it has nothing to do with a normal (Gaussian) distribution. “Normal” is a common word in math and has many meanings. Here, it means to make your sample have a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1. If your data are skewed, they will still be skewed. You don’t get a bell curve from this.

Comment: It’s this called standardization ?

Comment: Yes, but you'd also say "standardization" if you subtracted some other mean and/pr divided by some other standard deviation (like population values, or hypothesized values).. So just saying "standardization" alone is ambiguous; you need to say what things you're subtracting and dividing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you use the scale function in R then the means of both groups will be 0 and they will be equal by definition.

Second, when you have sample sizes this small, any data that are significantly different will pass the IOTT -- the interocular trauma test -- it hits you between the eyes.

Third, the Mann Whitney U test is not exactly a test of whether the means are equal. It is a test of whether

> it is equally likely that a randomly selected value from one sample
>   will be less than or greater than a randomly selected value from a
>   second sample.

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test)

the results will often be the same, but they are testing different things.

Finally, if you really want a test with these sample sizes you could do a permutation test. That is, you could look at every possible division of the data into groups of 4 and 5, take the means of each, take the differences and see where the difference in your case falls. There are only $9 \choose{5} $ possibilities.

Comment: But 4 of the observations are sample 1 and the others are from sample 2. Can I mixed them ?

Comment: Yes, and then separate them differntly. That's the point.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what method or purpose you have in mind by 'normalizing' and 'standardizing'. I'll try to give some helpful information.
Transforming the data can lead to difficulties interpreting the practical importance of any difference in means you may discover.

**Rely on the robustness of the Welch t test.** If data are roughly normal, and the two populations may have different variances, I would use a Welch two-sample
t-test. Other options are discussed later.

Suppose data are are from normal populations with $n_1 = 4, \mu_1 = 50, \sigma_1 = 2,$ and $n_2 = 5, \mu_2 = 55, \sigma_2 = 3,$ generated in R as follows:

```
set.seed(927)
x1 = round(rnorm(4, 50, 2), 2)
x2 = round(rnorm(5, 55, 3), 2) 

summary(x1);  sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  45.91   47.45   49.01   48.64   50.19   50.62 
[1] 2.145559
summary(x2);  sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  50.01   50.90   51.88   53.39   56.99   57.17 
[1] 3.433402
```

With such small samples, it is difficult to judge data for normality. [Although you can *see* above that I generated the data as normal, in a real-life application, we *would not know* whether the data are normal.] Only if there are extreme outliers would one ordinarily decide that data are sufficiently far from normal that a Welch t test would be invalid. Here we find a significant difference in means, rejecting $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ at the 5% level in favor
of $H_a: \mu_1 \ne \mu_2.$

```
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -2.5372, df = 6.7225, p-value = 0.04015
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -9.2190199 -0.2859801
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
  48.6375   53.3900
```

**Nonparametric 2-sample rank-based test.** Alternatively, you might use a nonparametric Wilcoxon rank sum test to see
if the populations 1 and 2 have different centers. Especially for very small
samples, this test is somewhat less powerful (able to detect differences between populations) than the Welch t test. We cannot reject $H_0$ at the 5% level. [In a real application, there is not much practical difference between a P-value of 0.4 and a P-value of 0.6--even though it has become customary to use (more or less mindlessly) the 5% level of significance as a 'standard'.]

```
wilcox.test(x1, x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x1 and x2
W = 2, p-value = 0.06349
alternative hypothesis: 
   true location shift is not equal to 0
```

**Simulated permutation test.** A nonparametric permutation test might also be a possibility here. We use
the pooled two-sample test statistic as the method of measuring distance
in location between the two populations. The P-value is slightly larger
than $0.05$ so we cannot reject the null hypothesis at the 5% level.

```
x = c(x1, x2);  g = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2)
stripchart(x ~ g, ylim=c(.5, 2.5), pch=19)
```

[image]

```
t.obs = t.test(x~g, var.eq=T)$stat
set.seed(2019)
t.prm = replicate(10^5, t.test(x~sample(g),var.eq=T)$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) >= abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.06386                          # P-value
hist(t.prm, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v = c(t.obs,-t.obs), col="red")
```

*Notes:* (a) The simulated permutation distribution is found by randomly
permuting the nine observations between the two groups; in the R code
`sample(g)` performs the permutation. (b) The logical vector 
`abs(t.prm) >= abs(t.obs)` contains $10^5$ `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s; its
`mean` is the proportion of its `TRUE`s, which is the P-value of the
simulated permutation test. (c) The figure below shows the simulated
permutation distribution for our data of the pooled t statistic. The
area in the histogram outside the vertical red lines is the P-value.
(d) [Q & A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409611/robust-two-sample-test-with-triplicate-measurements/409632#409632) shows a similar permutation test. Eudey (2010), *Journal of Stat. Educ.* has elementary discussions of permutation tests; see Section 3. (Google `Eudey permutation test` for current link.)

[image]